# in Python, why function parameter values are not updated upon call if default value is a method call?

Tags: python-3.x, parameter-passing

```
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep


def a1(v=datetime.utcnow()):
    print(v)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a1()
    sleep(1)
    a1()
```

```
result:
2020-07-06 11:26:31.959986
2020-07-06 11:26:31.959986
```

When calling a function that has for default parameter a method call, why is the result always the same?

shouldn't be executed every time the method is called?

Comment: it will not execute everytime @pedro Nunes

Comment: `def` statements are executed once. This question has some good explanations as to why that is. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument